# Importing into MS SQL Server: save and reuse column/data type mapping?

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I often have to import (messy) data from Excel or csv files into Microsoft SQL Server; the import tools rarely, if ever, guess the correct data types. Even when the data doesn't need to be cleansed, there are often too many NULLs in the first rows for the data type to be identified. Since I often receive periodic updates of the source files, it would be useful to have a way to define column mapping once and for all, and then be able to use this mapping on all subsequent files.

E.g. I receive the file 'sales_New_York_January'. I manually identify the data type of each column; can I save the column/data type association somewhere (a script, a separate file) so that, when I have to import another file with the same structure (sales_Los_Angeles_February), I don't have to assign data types manually all over again?

I am running Microsoft SQL Server 2014 and also have access to SQL Server Integration Services and to Pentaho. My preference would be for some kind of script-based solution, rather than having to go through hundreds of clicks in SSIS.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you considered Bulk Import w/ a Format File?  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178129.aspx

Comment: @Nathan, yes, I had thought about that, but creating them manually is more painful than coding in assembly, at least for me. I have tried many many times but always failed. Do you know of any tools which can help in creating format files? Thanks

Comment: You can use the [bcp utility](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191516(v=sql.105).aspx) to create format files for defined tables.

Answer (score 0):

> when I have to import another file with the same structure (sales_Los_Angeles_February), I don't have to assign data types manually all over again?

It almost sounds like you're creating a separate package for each file. If that's what's happening, and do they have the same physical structure, consider supplying the file name as a parameter or in a config file.

Can you create mapping tables in your SQL Server instance and use fairly standard mapping/lookup operations in SSIS?  We do this regularly, to the point that we're thinking about writing a custom component for specific cases.  You could save flat files or Excel files and load them for the same purpose, using an appropriate connector.

We have a boilerplate script component that inventories the entire package and builds column dictionaries to identify datatypes and other attributes by component that gets used in a couple of clients' specific packages, but I've never used the output to drive other components.

Comment: I'm not too familiar with SSIS. In fact, I typically prefer writing scripts to doing thousands of clicks in a graphical interface. Do you mean that, if I have a table which associates: Field1 -> int, Field2 -> date, etc, I can use this table with SSIS? If yes, could you explain how? Could I do the same with some script? Thanks!

Comment: You mention that these files have the same structure, yet you're recreating the type linkages. That suggests you're creating essentially the same package repeatedly, and that should not be necessary.  You can pass the file name to a standardised package and reuse the linkages you already have set up.


The mapping tables I was referring to are used to resolve input-value to system-valid-value, and re-reading your question probably don't apply here.